# How to declare a field in a custom entity as a geofield for leaflet views integration

Tags: entities, location

I am trying to use leaflet with a custom entity that has geocodes in them.

Below is the custom entity called Places.

```
function places_schema() {
$schema = array();

$schema['Places'] = array(
  'description' => 'Places',
  'fields' => array(
    'PlacesId' => array(
      'description' => 'PlacesId',
      'type' => 'serial',
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'Address1' => array(
      'description' => 'Address1',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'Address2' => array(
      'description' => 'Address2',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'City' => array(
      'description' => 'City',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'State' => array(
      'description' => 'State',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'ZipCode' => array(
      'description' => 'Zipcode',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'GeoLat' => array(
      'description' => 'Latitude',
      'type' => 'geofield',
      'not null' => FALSE,
      'precision' => '10',
      'scale' => '6',
    ),
    'GeoLon' => array(
      'description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
      'type' => 'geofield',
      'not null' => FALSE,
      'precision' => '10',
      'scale' => '6',
    ),
    'County' => array(
      'description' => 'Longitude',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'SortOrder' => array(
      'description' => 'Sort Order',
      'type' => 'int',
      'size' => 'big',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'Type' => array(
      'description' => 'Type of Address',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
    'GeoStatus' => array(
      'description' => 'Goecoded or not',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => '255',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'primary key' => array('PlacesId'),
  'indexes' => array(
    'City' => array(array('City', 15)),
    'County' => array('County'),
  ),
);
return $schema;
}
```

I can get the handlers to work but when I go to settings on the leaflet map in views it does not recognize my geofields.

```
class PlacesViewsController extends EntityDefaultViewsController {

public function views_data() {

        $data = parent::views_data();

        $data['Places']['GeoLat'] = array(
            'field name' => 'GeoLat',
            'title' => t('Latitude'),
            'help' => t('Geo Latitude for a Place'),
            'field' => array(
                'handler' => 'geofield_handler_field',
            ),
            'filter' => array(
                'handler' => 'geofield_handler_filter',
            ),
            'sort' => array(
                'handler' => 'geofield_handler_sort',
            ),
        );
        $data['Places']['GeoLon'] = array(
            'field name' => 'GeoLon',
            'title' => t('Longitude'),
            'help' => t('Geo Longitude for a Place'),
            'field' => array(
                'handler' => 'geofield_handler_field',
            ),
            'filter' => array(
                'handler' => 'geofield_handler_filter',
            ),
            'sort' => array(
                'handler' => 'geofield_handler_sort',
            ),
        );

        return $data;
}

}
```

Looking through the geofield modules there is a field formatter for geofield_lat and geofield_lon.  So I would think it would pick this up.

Do I need to implement hook__entity_property_info_alter?

Comment: IIUC you're trying to create an entity with a field 'built-in'. One of the neat features of having a Field API is that this isn't necessary - just create a fieldable entity, and then you can use the Field API to add the field to a particular entity bundle. You shouldn't need to consider the field's schema.

Comment: Thanks.  In my case, the entity is a custom database that already has the geofield (GeoLat and GeoLon) already filled out.